# Wireless driver for Lenovo Ideapad Y700?

Tags: wireless, drivers, lenovo, ideapad

Is anyone working on a wireless driver for the Lenovo Ideapad Y700 ?
I bought one for my son, who is in high school. The deal was that he had to run dual OS (Windows and Ubuntu) get familiar with Ubuntu, but at the moment the only way to establish a network connection with Ubuntu on this PC is by cable not the best "sales argument for Ubuntu" for this dad.
Wireless controller: `Intel 8260-AC (rev 3a)`.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: What is the Ubuntu and kernel version?

Answer (score 2):

While I am not running dual-boot, I did install Ubuntu 16.04lts on my new Lenovo Ideapad Y700 (first thing I did after making a disk image), and wifi worked out of the box. I was a little surprised since I did research and expected to have to use a work-around as above. In fact, the only thing that didn't work is multi-touch on the touch-screen, but the touch-screen as single-touch works fine! (Though I have yet to try 3d acceleration.)

(Answer added to old question to show that Ubuntu 16.04LTS works without work-around, for others researching compatibility with this laptop before purchase.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this command worked perfectly on my Ideapad Y700 Touch model.
You need to blacklist the Ideapad driver:

```
echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf
```

For some computers it's more easier to do:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
```

Your Wi-fi driver should be working now!